# Why does the chat FAQ say we have to be nice to people who don't deserve it?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-faq

From [the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#nice):

> Yes. We expect community members to treat each other with respect … **even when they don't deserve it.**

(*Emphasis mine.*)

Can anyone explain this rule?

Comment: [Do unto others as you would like them to do unto you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule)

Comment: @CodyGray Sure, if someone is nice to me, then I'll be nice to him. But if the guy is a jerk, why should I be nice to him?

Comment: Because we would like to rise above such things? Be the better person? Turn the other cheek?

Comment: This could certainly be worded differently.

Comment: I agree with not being an ass (although sometimes...), but treating with respect? No.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine "the golden rule" implies that if we all treat others as we would like to be treated this doesn't happen.

Comment: Imagine how quickly a "conversation" would devolve if we didn't follow this rule? 5 y/o name calling?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine If you have a problem with a user, you can always flag or walk away/ignore. As simple as that.

Comment: This rule also goes against everything I was taught in elementary school: "Respect should be earned, not given".

Comment: A good reason to treat other with respect when you think they don't deserve it is that you can be wrong. I've felt bad more than once after having been harsh and having understood after that it wasn't deserved...

Comment: Because what *he* thinks is being a jerk may not be the same thing *you* think constitutes being a jerk. Thus rudeness would be too easy to justify, and you'd have no meaningful standards for etiquette at all.

Comment: @rlemon Treating someone with respect and actually respecting them are two different things.

Comment: Being hostile and being blunt are also two different things. I can be blunt with a user (not sugar coat things) and it can be considered 'rude' or disrespectful.

Comment: @Oded you're just a mean old poopie-head.

Comment: I must admit, I'm rather tempted to flag this for migration to [philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: So you think when a moderator deletes a comment for being rude, the commenter can complain "Hold on, he was rude first!" and force the moderator to judge that before deleting the comment? No thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Should be more like:

```
...even when [you feel] they don't deserve it.
```

Everyone deserves to be treated with respect. When someone is being a jerk, being a jerk back only makes things worse, and chat starts to look like YouTube comments. It makes you look bad, and it makes us all look bad.

Of course, this applies to AFK as well.

Comment: AFK? What is this AFK of which you speak?

Comment: Like bathroom breaks, etc.

Comment: That's what laptops are for.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Or smartphones/tablets. #guiltyascharged

Answer (score 9):

[Network effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect). One guy being a jerk sucks. And that affects multiple people; that sucks even more. But what happens when you're a jerk to the jerk? A few things:

- The jerk lashes *back* that makes the *immediate* situation worse.
- Other people see this two-way jerkiness and it begins to appear to be the norm. Whether they agree with the jerk or with you, they will be more likely to view rudeness as a valid way to express their opinion.
- The additional rudeness directed in both directions will increase, often to at least one person's breaking point.

Network effects are sort of like a virus; if you can kill one "node" early, you can prevent lots of future growth. In this case, that's a good thing. By stemming the vitriol early you end up with a much more pleasant environment, even if it denies you the crude satisfaction of telling off that jerkass.

This is why, as a mod, I'll generally just fire off a "stop, now" warning or two and then just reach for the suspend button if excessive rudeness continues. Lashing out doesn't do anything, heck, engaging jerks *at all*, no matter how polite you are, is generally a bad idea. Some people are incapable of not being jerks, and being rude to them certainly won't stop them. At worst there are trolls who are specifically *trying* to elicit that negative reaction.

Just live and let live, and leave your attention to the people that care. Jerks don't generally care. Even if being rude to jerks *didn't* start a death-spiral of nastiness, there's still better things you could be doing with your time, on or off the site. Just do one of those things instead.

Answer (score 4):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

This site is not open to everyone. There is a specific subset of the population that should be represented here: programmers with a purpose.

If you fall into the "professional" category, you probably already know that politeness tends to lead to better results than standard emotional responses. Few things damage a workplace more than unchecked emotions, and the same holds true on a site geared toward professionals.

Enthusiasts should understand that they will get better help and acceptance from the community when they focus on the subject at hand without allowing emotions to cloud issues. The site specifically shuns discussion and opinion in favor of objectivity and experience. Emotional responses generally run counter to the core goal.

If someone is acting in a way that offends you, just remember that *this isn't real life*. It is the internet. You can walk away, and you will probably be the better person if you do.

Comment: Absolutely true, though there's no reason this shouldn't apply to *everyone*. Well, except talk-radio hosts.